# Rigging Challenges for fur and curves

Tags: animation, rigging, particles

I am having some challenges rigging and know here has to be a simple answer to this.  I created a furry figure but right now just placed the bones and linking, noticing the fur is not folloing the object when I move the bone but follows the object the fur is attached to.
[image: fur seperate from object on rigging]

Also, I am noticing ridges that are not smooth when I move the bone with the object attached as shown...there has to be a simple solution to this problem.

Thanks, any help greatly appreciated.

[image: edge when moved]

Answer (score 2):

particles(fur) doesn't update that fast try alt-a or a quick render it should be fine

Comment: This is a good answer. It definitely deserves some elaboration.

Comment: Thanks for the help but that didn't solve the problem.  The problem turned out to be my particle systems being in a wrong order in the modifier stack. I am still having challenges though with edges produced when I rotate the bone  at junctions.  I am using a graduated weight paint near the joints to smooth it out but is still seems that when I turn a bone, the object still has an edge on it when I turn it as shown by the image in the original post